# Best practice for setting a lower hierarchy private field in c++

Tags: c++, oop

I have to following classes:

```
//file: A.h
class A
{
    private:
       int num;
    public:
       A(int num);
       void setNum(int num);
       int getNum();       
};

//file B.h
class B
{
    private:
       A a;
    public:
       B(int num);   
       A getA();
};
```

Class A is contained in class B. Class A has a private field 'num'. Class A has  a public getter and a setter for the private field 'num'. When constructing an object in class B, it forwards the value of 'num' to the object A it contains.

After I create object B (and therefore also the contained object A) what is the best practice to set the value of A.num to a different value from the context of B.

For instance, this doesn't seem to work:

```
// file main.cc
int main()
{ 
    B b(5);
    B.getA().setNum(7);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: You should return a reference in the getter: `A& getA();` to make this working as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define a member function in B to set the value of A:

```
void B::setA(int k) {
    a.setNum(k);
}
```

Comment: did you mean `B::setNum`?

Comment: In my case, there are actually more than two hierarchies (closer to 5). So this solution is a lot of work, but it still seem the better way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As @πάντα ῥεῖ commented, your getter `A getA()` returns a temporal object which will be destroyed when out of the scope of `getA()`. So you should return a reference to the private field `a` using `A &getA()`. And then you could call any public method of class A via `getA()`.

Taking a step further, using `A &getA()`, however, gives clients control to your private member, which is usually not a good idea. That is, one can change your private field `a` with another object of class A like using `getA() = A2`. You should add a constant version: `const A &getA() const;`

Therefore, just add one more method in class B as @kiviak answered, which I personally think, is the best practice for your requirement.

Comment: I think you should generally avoid returning "handles" to object internals if you can. I think kiviak's answer is more encapsulated.

Comment: @Chris Drew +1. As I revised just now.